# Invalid bitfield flag or number: undefined

Tags: discord.js

So i went to start my discord.js bot and then this error shown.

```js
  throw new RangeError('BITFIELD_INVALID', bit);
    ^

RangeError [BITFIELD_INVALID]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: undefined.
    at Function.resolve (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:152:11)
    at /home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:147:54
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.resolve (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:147:40)
    at Client._validateOptions (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:546:33)
    at new Client (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:73:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/container/index.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'BITFIELD_INVALID'}
```

Can anyone help at all, a list of my commands can be found at https://github.com/Makuta24/commands
Thanks in advance! Ps i do not know what code made this error occur therefor i linked all of the commands on the server, sorry.

Comment: Show us the code that made the error not the folder filled with alot of file commands pls

Comment: I am not sure what code made the error therefor I have linked all the commands. Sorry about this I have never had this error before.

Comment: Well from your error `at Object.<anonymous> (/home/container/index.js:4:16)` the problem comes from your file index.js, the 4th line and 16th character, maybe you could show me the line (and maybe the 4 precedent and next line with it) so I can better understand the problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS] });

@MalikLahlou

Comment: @GeorgeAston edit it and make it `new Client({intents : ['GUILDS','GUILD_MESSAGES','GUILD_MESSAGES_REACTIONS']})`

Comment: @GeorgeAston It's a typo, `Intents.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` should be `Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS`

Answer (score 0):

An error I noticed on your code, is that you are requesting permissions with the `hasPermission()` modal. In v13 (version I suppose you are using), [this modal is deprecated.](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#guildmember)

Here is a solution that may work for you:

```
const { MessageEmbed, Permissions } = require('discord.js');

if (!message.member.permissions.has([Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_CHANNELS])) {
    return message.channel.send('Wait, you cannot lock channels!')
}
```

What I am doing here is requesting the `Permissions` object from the Discord.js library, to use it with your chosen flag (`FLAGS.MANAGE_CHANNELS`), and then checking if it has the flag you expect with the `has()` modal.

This is only what I saw on the command's code, though. Your error log shows an error on `index.js:4:16`, so it may be a good idea to share your `index.js` file to see if there are other errors present on it.